# How to use Try Catch

Tags: vb.net

My project includes 1000 lines code.

I want to see if any error exists during my project is running.

Following code is okey for this?

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        'My 1000 lines code here
        '....................
        '....................
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Go to menu DEBUG-EXCEPTIONS-MANAGED, and click THROW. This way you will see all exceptions when you debug

Comment: There **is** a place, that is easy to find which has comprehensive coverage of all things NET related.  Including [Try/Catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz(v=VS.100).aspx).  Visit soon, visit often, add to bookmarks and Profit!

Answer (score 0):

That is fine ...

I normally try to back things up in to individual pieces and catch different errors to do different things

```
Try

Catch ioexp As IO.FileNotFoundException

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```